# How to call an AJAX function on anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using PHP, jQuery, AJAX, Smarty for my website. I'm having following line of code from smarty template. I wan to call the jQuery AJAX function on the onclick of that hyperlink but I'm not able to call it. Can you help me in giving call to the jQuery AJAX function?
Following is my code.
Code from Smarty template:

```
<a class="edit_user_transaction_status" href="{$control_url}{$query_path}?op=edit_user_transaction&page={$page}&txn_no={$user_transaction_details.transaction_no}&transaction_data_assign={$user_transaction_details.transaction_data_assign}&user_id={$user_id}{if $user_name!=''}&user_name={$user_name}{/if}{if $user_email_id!=''}&user_email_id={$user_email_id}{/if}{if $user_group!=''}&user_group={$user_group}&{/if}{if $user_sub_group!=''}&user_sub_group={$user_sub_group}{/if}{if $from_date!=''}&from_date={$from_date}{/if}{if $to_date!=''}&to_date={$to_date}{/if}{if $transaction_status!=''}&transaction_status={$transaction_status}{/if}{if $transaction_no!=''}&transaction_no={$transaction_no}{/if}">Update</a>
```

jQuery AJAX function is as follows:

```
$(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function(e) { 
         e.preventDefault();
         //for confirmation that status change
         var ans=confirm("Are you sure to change status?");
         if(!ans) {
             return false;
         }  
         var post_url           = $(this).attr('href');
         var transaction_status_update = $('#transaction_status_update').val();      

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: post_url+"&transaction_status_update="+transaction_status_update,
                 data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',  
             success: function(data) {              
                 var error = data.login_error;

                 $(".ui-widget-content").dialog("close");
                //This variables use for display title and success massage of transaction update              
                 var dialog_title   = data.title;              
                 var dialog_message = data.success_massage; 
                 //This get link where want to rerdirect
                 var redirect_link  = data.href;            

                 var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,
                     height: 80,
                     close: function(){                                     
                         document.location.href =redirect_link;
                     }                  
                 });                    

                 $dialog.dialog('open');                    
             }          
        });
     });
});
```

If I try to print the alert at the beginning of function it's not getting printed. Can you help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap all your code in function and call in <a href="javascript:yourfunction()">

Comment: make sure you have your script inside .. document.ready function `$(function(){..})`

Comment: There is like an entire program in just an A tag...

Comment: Is it wrapped in `$( document).ready() {}` ? [link](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: what alert is not working? have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Yes it is wrapped in side $(document).ready()

Comment: is your `<a>` tag appended dynamically??

Comment: Your code has an extra set of `});` at the end, which aren't needed.

Comment: }) that is for closing the $(document).ready() block

Comment: No errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console at all.

Comment: so you're not getting the confirmation alert?

Comment: Would you mention your jquery version.

Comment: Where does the code stop working? From the AJAX call? Have you looked in the network tab of firebug or chromes developer tools to see what XHR response your getting ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not able to call the function.

Comment: OK, so the click works, but the AJAX doesn't ? You need to debug the AJAX call by inspecting the HTTP header of the call/response. See my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected Code:

```
$(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function(e) { 
         e.preventDefault();
         //for confirmation that status change
         var ans=confirm("Are you sure to change status?");
         if(!ans) {
             return false;
         }  
         var post_url           = $(this).attr('href');
         var transaction_status_update = $('#transaction_status_update').val();      

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: post_url+"&transaction_status_update="+transaction_status_update,
                 data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',  
             success: function(data) {              
                 var error = data.login_error;

                 $(".ui-widget-content").dialog("close");
                //This variables use for display title and success massage of transaction update              
                 var dialog_title   = data.title;              
                 var dialog_message = data.success_massage; 
                 //This get link where want to rerdirect
                 var redirect_link  = data.href;            

                 var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,
                     height: 80,
                     close: function(){                                     
                         document.location.href =redirect_link;
                     }                  
                 });                    

                 $dialog.dialog('open');                    
             }          
        });
     });
```

Note: Remove `});` from the last line.