# Another request is redirected but the previous url stay unchanged

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I mouseover `edit` at the bottom of stackoverflow's question like
[javascript - How to call an AJAX function on anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779494/how-to-call-an-ajax-function-on-anchor-tag)

It's url address appears as

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18779494/edit

However, if I clicked the link, an edit form emerged but the url address stayed unchanged,

It's not `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18779494/edit` but still manifest itself as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779494/how-to-call-an-ajax-function-on-anchor-tag`

How to perform this magic tricks?

Answer (score 2):

It is intercepted via javascript which also stops redirection but incase the javascript is disabled or there are some JS erros you would be redirected to the href. It's a best practise to have your website work without JS as well.